# Downloading and importing labels for CanVec Named Features (Code 1580010) layer (Natural Resources Canada)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, canada

I used the CanVec symbology toolkit (described at [Canvec Symbology in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7031/canvec-symbology-in-arcgis-desktop)) to symbolize all the downloaded data but now I am wanting to download and import labels or a procedure that I should follow for creating all necessary labels.

I have an add-on that I can use to import labels from another layer so ideally I would like to obtain a layer file that already has all the labels classes defined and properly symbolized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a CONCISCODE field in the NAMED FEATURES POINT feature class.  The codes are described on page 15 of [this](http://ftp2.cits.rncan.gc.ca/pub/canvec/doc/CanVec_feature_catalogue_en.pdf) document but I have not been able to find a look-up table.

This replaces the legacy NTDB classes (Hydrography, Place, Shoreline, Relief, Transport, Unknown)

This is not really a answer to the specific question but once I can create the various label classes I will be able to re-use the layer and re-import the labels to other layers as needed.